# Perf trace calling function

Tags: linux, perf

I am learning how to use perf. I have used perf stat followed by perf report. So I noticed that I was getting cache misses in memcpy. Is it possible to do a backtrace of some sort to figure out which memcpy this is? Just knowing that it's from memcpy is pretty useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing `-g` flag to `perf record` will make it collect the call stacks with each event. Viewing `perf report` for a trace collected with the `-g` flag will help you understand where the problematic `memcpy` was called from. You may also want to use the `--children` flag of the `perf report` command.